# It appears my for loop is running twice, how do I fix (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var MarkUpChecker = (function iffe() {
  'use strict';
  var URLS = {
      'foo': 'http://foo.com',
      'bar': 'http://bar.com',
      'baz': 'http://baz.com',
      'yay': 'http://www.yay.com',
      'blargh': 'http://www.blargh.com'
    },

    publicAPI;

  function getURL() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      return URLS[arguments[i]];
    }
  }

  publicAPI = {

    addURL: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 2) {
        URLS[arguments[i]] = arguments[i + 1];
      }
      console.dir(URLS);
      return URLS;
    },
    addTag: function() {
      var doc = document,
        internal_h1 = doc.querySelectorAll('.internal_h1'),
        sheet = doc.createElement('style');
      for (var i = 0; i < internal_h1.length; i++) {
        internal_h1[i].innerHTML = '<h1>' + internal_h1[i].innerHTML + '</h1>';
        sheet.innerHTML = 'h1 {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important; font-weight: 200!important; font-size: 22px !important; color: #333; margin: 3px 0px 6px; line-height: 24px !important;};'
        doc.body.appendChild(sheet);
      }
    },

    searchDoc: function() {
      function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
      }

      var link, url, parser, newPathName = '',
        emailUrl = /img\//gi,
        tsUrl = /\/REPSuite\/static\/html\/inews_archives\/img\//gi,
        newstr = '',
        doc = document,
        container,
        container_id,
        container_links,
        container_images,
        documentTableWrapper,
        docBodyFirstChild,
        nodeToTargetToInsertLP;

      if (!doc.getElementById('container')) {
        container = doc.createElement('div');
        container.setAttribute('id', 'container');
        container.className = 'container-avon-representative-news';
        container_links = container.getElementsByTagName('a');
        container_id = doc.getElementById('container');
        docBodyFirstChild = doc.body.firstChild;
        nodeToTargetToInsertLP = doc.getElementsByClassName('flexTile')[4];


        if (nodeToTargetToInsertLP) {
          documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByClassName('marginfix')[0];
          container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
          insertAfter(container, nodeToTargetToInsertLP);
        } else {
          documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
          container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
          doc.body.insertBefore(container, docBodyFirstChild);
        }


      } else {
        container_links = doc.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('a');
      }
      container_images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
      for (var i = 0; i < container_images.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[0] == "foo" || arguments[1] == "bar") {
          container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/images/news/');
        } else {
          container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/static/images/alt_news/');

        }
      }

      for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        url = getURL(arguments[i]);
        for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
          link = container_links[j];

          if (link.href.indexOf(url) != -1) {
            parser = document.createElement('a');
            parser.href = link.href;

            link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
            newPathName = parser.pathname;


            if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) {
              newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
              newstr = newPathName;
              link.href = newstr;

            }
          } else {
            link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
          }
        }

      }
    }
  };
  return publicAPI;
})();
```

My problem is my for loop seems to run over the links twice and  overwrites the initial adding of this attribute:

```
 link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
```

with this attribute:

```
 link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
```

This is an excerpt of a function which can be found in the snippet above.

```
         for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
            url = getURL(arguments[i]);
            for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
                link = container_links[j];

                if (link.href.indexOf(url) != -1) { //problem seems to be here
                    parser = document.createElement('a');
                    parser.href = link.href;

                    link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
                    newPathName = parser.pathname;


                    if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) {
                        newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
                        newstr = newPathName;
                        link.href = newstr;

                    }
                } else {
                    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                }
            }

    }
```

To give you some background the script's main function is to automate redundant tasks I have to do weekly to a newsletter which is repurposed to a static web-page/landing page:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://foo.com/path/to_page.aspx"> 
    <img src="img/some_image.jpg">
</a>
```

The script goes through the DOM, looks for URLS which match a condition and strips out the base URL, some of the pathname and applies target `_self` to the `href`

It also changes the pathnames of my images!

In the HTML I call this function which accepts a string:

```
    MarkUpChecker.searchURL('foo', 'bar');
```

That string represents the URL I would like to target and to have the changes applied  :

```
    var URLS = {
        'foo': 'http://foo.com',
        'bar': 'http://bar.com',
        'baz': 'http://baz.com',
        'yay': 'http://www.yay.com',
        'blargh': 'http://www.blargh.com'
    },
```

This function is used to cycle through the object:

```
    function getURL() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            return URLS[arguments[i]];
        }
    }
```

And lastly this is the `searchURL` function:

```
 searchURL: function() {
            function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
                referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
            }

            var link, url, parser, newPathName = '',
                emailUrl = /img\//gi,
                tsUrl = /\/REPSuite\/static\/html\/inews_archives\/img\//gi,
                newstr = '',
                doc = document,
                container,
                container_id,
                container_links,
                container_images,
                documentTableWrapper,
                docBodyFirstChild,
                nodeToTargetToInsertLP;

            if (!doc.getElementById('container')) {
                container = doc.createElement('div');
                container.setAttribute('id', 'container');
                container.className = 'container-avon-representative-news';
                container_links = container.getElementsByTagName('a');
                container_id = doc.getElementById('container');
                docBodyFirstChild = doc.body.firstChild;
                nodeToTargetToInsertLP = doc.getElementsByClassName('flexTile')[4];


                if (nodeToTargetToInsertLP) {
                    documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByClassName('marginfix')[0];
                    container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
                    insertAfter(container, nodeToTargetToInsertLP);
                } else {
                    documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
                    container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
                    doc.body.insertBefore(container, docBodyFirstChild);
                }


            } else {
                container_links = doc.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('a');
            }
            container_images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
            for (var i = 0; i < container_images.length; i++) {
                if (arguments[0] == "foo" || arguments[1] == "bar") {
                    container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/images/news/');
                } else {
                    container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/static/images/alt_news/');

                }
            }

            for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
                url = getURL(arguments[i]);
                for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
                    link = container_links[j];

                    if (link.href.indexOf(url) != -1) {
                        parser = document.createElement('a');
                        parser.href = link.href;

                        link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
                        newPathName = parser.pathname;


                        if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) {
                            newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
                            newstr = newPathName;
                            link.href = newstr;

                        }
                    } else {
                        link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

What I have observed via the debugger is while it **does** strip out the path name it applies target `_blank` to all the `hrefs`

Also—The funny thing is the script works in another context/environment which doesn't need to go through this part of the code:

```
 if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) {
    newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
    newstr = newPathName;
    link.href = newstr;

}
```

It works perfectly in that case.

Comment: Use the browser's Javascript debugger. Set breakpoints at the two `setAttribute` lines, then you can see how you're getting there each time.

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry I mislabeled `searchDoc` should be `searchURL`

Comment: @Gary someone suggested because of all my updates in that question I open a new question. I really didn't want to and the community seemed keep upvoting my updates, but I suppose I caved to his perspective...

Comment: The problem is that there's lots of history in the comments over there, which are all lost if a new question is started.

Comment: @Barmar Good point should I just delete it? I thought I was on the right track over there; But felt he had a point. With one of the updates I kind of landed with another request, i.e. I discovered the loop was running twice....Thanks pal.